# excel vba - open a previous saved document

Tags: excel, vba, reference, ms-word

I am really stuck on this one and don't know where to start really. Still new to VBA.

I got a code that writes textbox values from a userform into a word document using bookmarks. This document is then saved to C:\documents after clicking submit.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to use another command button on the userform to open that saved file based on one of the values I entered previously and amend the document when needed.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

This is what I have that works to write to word doc from a userform when i click submit button. But I added another command button to recall that doc based on the textbox value within the userform example, Userform textbox1 value is 3. So when i click on edit command button, it recalls the doc that has that value in its content i.e. bookmark1 = 3

```
        '----------The Script below writes values to the document ----------------------- 
     -----------------

    Dim wApp As Object
    Dim wDoc As Object

    'We need to continue through errors since if Word isn't
    'open the GetObject line will give an error

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")


'We've tried to get Word but if it's nothing then it isn't open
If wApp Is Nothing Then
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

'It's good practice to reset error warnings
On Error GoTo 0

'Open your document and ensure its visible and activate after openning

Set wDoc = 
wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Documents\template.docx ", 
ReadOnly:=False)
    With wDoc
    .Bookmarks("bookmark1").Range.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark2").Range.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark3").Range.Text = Me.TextBox4.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark4").Range.Text = Me.TextBox5.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark5").Range.Text = Me.TextBox6.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark6").Range.Text = Me.TextBox7.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark7").Range.Text = Me.TextBox8.Value
    End With

wApp.Visible = True

'set default file name and file path

ProposedFileName = Format(Now(), "DDMMMYYYY") &  
TextBox1.Value & "-" & TextBox2.Value & ".doc"
ProposedFilePath = "C:\Users\Documents\"

    With wApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    wDoc.SaveAs2 ProposedFilePath & ProposedFileName, _
    FilterIndex = 1, _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument

    End With   
End Sub
```

On another userform has an edit button that when clicked, is to recall the saved doc from the above script. Something like below maybe?

```
Sub EditButton_Cick()
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Documents\SavedDoc.docx ", 
ReadOnly:=False) 'here is where I want to open the previous saved document located in C:\Documents from the script in my initial question however it should open the` doc referenced to textbox1.value
    With wDoc
    .Bookmarks("bookmark10").Range.Text = Me.TextBox10.Value 'In the userform, I add in another value later to the saved document

   objDoc.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, it’s probably possible. Share with us what you have so far and maybe a picture of the document

Comment: Save the path in a global variable in the form - then you can access it later (assuming you're still in that userform)

Comment: @Tim Williams. Sorry for the late response, what do you mean by saving in a global variable?

Comment: It will be easier to show if you include the relevant parts of your current code.  Basically just declare a variable at the top of your Form code module, outside of any Sub/Function, and set that variable from the "submit" method.  You can then read it later from any other method.

Comment: Hi all, Can anyone point me in the direction of how open a previous saved document for re-editing based on a specific bookmark field within the document that matches a textbox value in the userform

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for replying but I don't know where to start really as I am new to VBA

Comment: I have edited my original post to include the scripts I have to write to a document file and then saves it in C:\documents\. But what I want to do is open that file later using a command button for editing and saving it over again. The command button would open the saved document based on a bookmark value within the doc that matches the textbox value in the userform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

At the top of a regular code module:

```
Dim savePath As String '<< global variable for saved file path
```

In your first userform:

```
Sub cmdSave_Click()
    '...
    '...
    savePath = ProposedFilePath & ProposedFileName  '<< save to Global var

    wDoc.SaveAs2 ProposedFilePath & ProposedFileName, _
        FilterIndex = 1, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
    '...
    '...
End Sub
```

In some later userform:

```
Sub cmdReOpenFile_Click()

    Dim doc
    '...
    Set doc = wApp.Documents.Open(savePath) '<< read from global var
    '... work with doc

End Sub
```

FYI it looks like you're using late binding so you will need to define any Word constants such as `wdFormatDocument`

If you put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code modules it will warn you about things like that.

Comment: Thank you but do I put this code in the "edit doc" command button?

Comment: The second sub is a stub for your "edit" button code

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that the edit button is not in the same userform. It is in another userform

Comment: Wiliams when I try your method it does not work. I think this is because the reopen button is on another useform

Comment: You can look at adding a public variable to a regular module - once you set the value, that will stay in scope as long as the document is open.

Comment: I have added more to the original questions with better explanation as I am still confused

Comment: On the second part of your answer that says on a later userform, how do I call that savePath variable from another userform where my open saved document button is located?

Comment: It could be another userform or a later opening of the same userform.  It doesn't matter which.